# Code run successfully but no results

Tags: python

I'm a newer to python and am learning how to scrape data using the book "Visualize This" by Nathan Yau. I'm trying to scrape Wunderground for the year 2016. My code run successfully, but no any results in wunder-data.txt. I am pretty confused.

Below is my code:

```
import sys
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
from codecs import open

# Create/open a file called wunder.txt (which will be a comma-delimited file)
#open('wunder-data.txt', 'w', encoding='utf8')

# Iterate through months and day
for m in range(1, 13):
for d in range(1, 32):

    # Check if already gone through month
    if (m == 2 and d > 28):
        break
    elif (m in [4, 6, 9, 11] and d > 30):
        break

# Open wunderground.com url
url = "https://www.wunderground.com/history/airport/KMHK/2016/" + str(m) + "/" + str(d) + "/DailyHistory.html"
page = urllib2.urlopen(url)

# Get temperature from pagef
soup = BS(page, "html.parser")
# dayTemp = soup.body.nobr.b.string
dayTemp = soup.find("span", text="Mean Temperature").parent.find_next_sibling("td").get_text(strip=True)

# Format month for timestamp
if len(str(m)) < 2:
    mStamp = '0' + str(m)
else:
    mStamp = str(m)

# Format day for timestamp
if len(str(d)) < 2:
    dStamp = '0' + str(d)
else:
    dStamp = str(d)

# Build timestamp
timestamp = '2016' + mStamp + dStamp

# Write timestamp and temperature to file
#s = (timestamp + ',' + dayTemp + '\n').encode('utf-8')
# or, cleaner:
s = u'{},{}\n'.format(timestamp, dayTemp).encode('utf-8')

# Done getting data! Close file.
```

Answer (score 1):

Near the top of the file,
you have this:

```
open('wunder-data.txt', 'w', encoding='utf8')
```

This opens a file for writing and returns a filehandle to it.
But you haven't stored the filehandle,
so you cannot write to it.
There is nothing in your posted code that would write to this file.

It's also unclear what you want to write to the file.
If it's the value of `s` you set at the end of your script,
then delete the `open(...)` call at the top,
and add this after you set `s` at the end:

```
with open('wunder-data.txt', 'w', encoding='utf8') as fh:
    fh.write(s.decode('utf8'))
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Actually I want know the average temperature of one place in 2016. But it only shows the last day's temperature. Do you know why? Thank you!

Comment: Yes, but that's a different question. And you will need to do some debugging yourself, so that you can ask a well-formed question that will be well-received. You really need to read carefully the [how-to-ask](/help/how-to-ask) page before posting any more questions.

Answer (score 1):

```
with open('wunder-data.txt', 'w', encoding='utf8') as file_descriptor:
    # do something to obtain the data
    # and do not forget to write the result to the file_descriptor:
    file_descriptor.write("My desired string.")
    # otherwise it is not suprising to be confused
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I am trying to get the average temperature of one place in 2016. But it only shows the last day's temperature. Can you take a look at my code? Thank you very much!